# What are some Python libraries written to demostrate Functional Reactive Programming?

Tags: python, asynchronous, functional-programming, reactive-programming

We handle huge data streams through our socket servers and in need of a non-block way to management callbacks to prevent race conditions.

Recently I came to know about functional reactive programming a method of programming and the solution is just what we are looking for.

There are examples in Haskell ([reactive banana](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana)), ClojureScript and Javascript ([bacon js](https://github.com/raimohanska/bacon.js)), but none for python. Are there any libraries written for Python enabling Functional Reactive Programming? If there aren't any libraries, where is a good place to start? What are the possible challenges to write one?

Answer (score 8):

There's an official Microsoft *wip* Rx (Reactive Extensions) implementation for Python called [Rx.py](http://rxpy.codeplex.com).

This project targets Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

I just checked the Wikipedia article on reactive programming, and in there, three modules are mentioned. You could check those out:

- [Trellis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Trellis)
- [Yoopf](https://sites.google.com/site/yoopforg/home?pli=1)
- [Traits](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/)

Comment: I will take a look at [Trellis](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/Trellis). Was hoping for something more current.